# How do I use a k8s serviceaccount's attached IAM role to make a request to S3 with the AWS SDK for Go v2

Tags: go, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-go, k8s-serviceaccount

In a Go application run as a k8s Job, I am attempting to assume a serviceaccount <-> IAM Role when trying to GetObject from an S3 bucket. I attach a `serviceAccountName` field to the Job spec in the yaml file, and I attach the AWS IAM to the service account. I have verified that the role has access to the S3 bucket in question.

The serviceaccount is created and seems to have the correct annotations:

```
Name:                identity
Namespace:           identity
Labels:              app=identity
Annotations:         eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::<acct-id>:role/identity-s3-role-dev
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   identity-token-bf2wz
Tokens:              identity-token-bf2wz
Events:              <none>
```

In my `kubectl describe pod <name>` , I see in the environment section:

```
      AWS_REGION:                   us-east-1
      AWS_ROLE_ARN:                 arn:aws:iam::<id>:role/identity-s3-role-dev
      AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE:  /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount from aws-iam-token (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-7rx85 (ro)
```

which implies that the pod has assumed the correct role (identity-s3-role-dev), and that the token file is mounted and all that.

But, that IAM role is not being used to talk to S3. When I execute my code, I get an error message:

```
panic: operation error S3: PutObject, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 4TFT6G0T08547RBQ, HostID: r2+1NduQf+v4F1gL/AlERLrNtJR1jeI9mIL7oKoWUFLvuY7lyq+Ug9ElK3YHvl5h8rsbgq/uRAw=, api error AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: The authorization header is malformed; a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential.
```

No authentication at all appears to be attached to the PutObject request.

As for the Go code, I'm using the AWS SDK v2 with these imports:

```
    awsconfig "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
```

to load the config here:

```
    localconfig := load_config() // this loads my configuration with viper

    cfg, err := awsconfig.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    client = s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    input := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Body:   manager.ReadSeekCloser(bytes.NewReader(b)), // b is the payload
        Bucket: &localconfig.s3bucket,
        Key:    &localconfig.s3key,
    }

    _, err = client.PutObject(context.TODO(), input)
```

The one thing I can think of that I am not sure is that I do not specify to use any sort of profile when loading configuration. But the AWS SDK docs seem to imply that if my pod has access to AWS creds through a service account (which I think I demonstrated is true above) they will be auto-loaded by the `LoadDefaultConfig` functionality.

So, what steps am I missing to get my credentials for the indicated service account and IAM role attached to my S3 put request?

---

Edit, I have been working on this for about a day now, and this is what I have discovered.

In order to get header information attached so that we no longer get that 400 error, you add in the configuration of the go code:

```
    cfg, err := awsconfig.LoadDefaultConfig(
        context.TODO(),
        awsconfig.WithSharedConfigProfile("anything"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

This changes the error message to:

```
operation error S3: GetObject, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 3H40VPYKAF64E0ZY, HostID: <long-id>, api error AccessDenied: Access Denied
```

The long as the short of it is, I am now attempting to access using the role of the associated nodes: `arn:aws:iam::<acct-id>:role/node_group01-eks-node-group-20220420182829219400000001`. This role does not have the required access, I want `arn:aws:iam::<acct-id>:role/identity-s3-role-dev`. Since I don't have access, I am getting a 403 now, which is expected.

So it seems like the problem might be on the Go SDK side, where I am not picking up the correct credentials.

I do note that it does not appear to matter what I put in with `"anything"` string, I always appear to pull the same node role credentials (which must be the default or something) and that gives me the 403 error.